# Preencher string com zeros a esquerda

Tags: java, string

Estou fazendo um trabalho de Sistemas Operacionais e precisando transformar números decimais em binários. Até ai tudo bem, pois o método abaixo recebe um inteiro e converte para binário. Meu problema é o seguinte:

Quando coloco, por exemplo (inteiro 1), ele me retorna corretamente 1. Mas tenho um valor armazenado que seria a quantidade de dígitos, por exemplo (qtd = 4). Eu gostaria que a string aparecesse desta forma: 0001 com quatro dígitos.

Teria como neste método realizar este procedimento, independente do valor da variável quantidade de dígitos?

```
public String converteDecimalParaBinario(int valor) {
   int resto = -1;
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   if (valor == 0) {
      return "0";
   }

   // enquanto o resultado da divisão por 2 for maior que 0 adiciona o resto ao início da String de retorno
   while (valor > 0) {
      resto = valor % 2;
      valor = valor / 2;
      sb.insert(0, resto);
   }

   return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cara não testei mas isso deve funcionar!

```
public String converteDecimalParaBinario(int valor) {
   int resto = -1;
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   int len=0;   

   if (valor == 0) {
      return "0000";
   }

   // enquanto o resultado da divisão por 2 for maior que 0 adiciona o resto ao início da String de retorno
   while (valor > 0) {
      resto = valor % 2;
      valor = valor / 2;
      sb.insert(0, resto);
   }
   len = sd.length();
   while(len<4){
       sd="0"+sd;
       len++;
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

**O que eu fiz:**

Iniciei uma variável do tipo `int` chamada `len`e atribui o tamanho do `sd` para `len` com o comando `len = sd.length();`.
Se `len` for menor que 4 adiciona 0 a esquerda, repete até len ser igual a 4.
retorna sd.

Comment: Deu certo! :D Apenas mudei para transformar StringBuilder para String.

Comment: Voltando nesta questão, ficou apenas uma coisa incorreta @Joannis... Quando o inteiro é 0 ele imprime `0` ao envés de utilizar as 4 casas e imprimir isto `0000`. Como fazer para ficar os 4 zeros?

Comment: ele retorna 0 por isso 

    if (valor == 0) {
          return "0";
       }

altere para isso:

    if (valor == 0) {
              return "0000";
           }

Comment: Ok. Funcionou :D Obrigado, não tinha me ligado nisto

Answer (score 15):

Você pode usar a classe DecimalFormat para formatar seu valor de saída. Assim:

```
    //coloque isso no final do seu método converteDecimalParaBinario
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000");
    return df.format(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
```

Você diz no enunciado que possui uma variável `qtd` que indica a quantidade de dígitos que deve possuir a saída, portanto, a construção do seu objeto de DecimalFormat deve ser variável de acordo com essa quantidade. Para fazer essa quantidade variável de digitos, você pode fazer um `for` e construir seu pattern. Exemplo:

```
    int qtd = 5;
    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<qtd; i++) {
        pattern.append("0");
    }
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern.toString());
```

Caso não faça parte do seu trabalho converter o número para binário também pode usar o método `toBinaryString()` da classe Integer para fazer a conversão para você. Exemplo:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Bin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(converteDecimalParaBinario(4));
    }
    public static String converteDecimalParaBinario(int valor) {
        int qtd = 5;
        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<qtd; i++) {
            pattern.append("0");
        }
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern.toString());
        return df.format(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(valor)));
    } 
}
```

Saída:

> 00100

Para trocar a quantidade de dígitos que a saída terá, basta alterar o valor da variável `qtd`.

Comment: +1 por fazer a API trabalhar para você em vez de reinventar a roda.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, porém já consegui com a proposta do @Joannis

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto, aqui no Stack a gente agradece com votos positivos ;)

Answer (score 10):

Podes realizar da seguinte forma se for uma *string*:

```
String str = "123";
String formatted = ("0000" + str).substring(str.length());
```

<sup>**Nota:** Meter um zero por cada digito pretendido, ou seja, 4 dígitos que mencionas na pergunta carecem 4 zeros.</sup>

Ou se for numero:

```
Int number = 123;
String formatted = String.format("%04d", number);
```

<sup>**Nota:** $04d é para quadro dígitos, $05d é para 5 dígitos, etc...</sup>

De qualquer maneira, a segunda opção é sempre melhor: ter a variável com o tipo correto e formatar da forma pretendida o número fazendo uso do método [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

---

Para o teu caso em particular, poderias fazer da seguinte forma na altura de devolver o valor:

```
String formatado = String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
return formatado;
```

## Exemplo

```
/* package superBuBu; */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        int valor = 1;
        int resto = -1;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (valor == 0) {
            System.out.println("0");
        }

        // enquanto o resultado da divisão por 2 for maior que 0 adiciona o resto ao início da String de retorno
        while (valor > 0) {
            resto = valor % 2;
            valor = valor / 2;
            sb.insert(0, resto);
        }

        String formatado = String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));

        System.out.println(formatado);
    }
}
```

Exemplo a funcionar no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/iQGrpJ).

Comment: Não consegui compreender aonde eu coloco isto em meu método para ele me retornar o que preciso:
qtd=4;
valor = 2;
String Retorna no método: '10'
Eu quero que ela retorne '0010'

Comment: @Zuul repare que o AP fala sobre a qtd variável de dígitos que a saída deve possuir. O seu código exibe 4 dígitos sempre. Demorei para perceber isso também, mas já consertei ;)

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, porém já consegui com a proposta do @Joannis

Comment: @Math Será? A pergunta não me parece transmitir isso. A resposta aceite apesar de usar mais código e ciclos, acaba por devolver 4 dígitos... ou estou a ler isto tudo mal?

Comment: @Zuul é que eu não fiquei tentando entender a resposta aceita pois achei confusa. Mas lendo o comentário do AP na sua resposta e esse trecho da pergunta "Mas tenho um valor armazenado que seria a quantidade de dígitos (qtd = 4)" eu entendi isso. Está bem confuso, mas foi o que eu entendi.

Comment: Ah sim, `len<4` e `len++` dentro do método faz com que sempre a saída tenha 4 dígitos. Enfim... se o AP diz que o problema resolvido então tá resolvido.

Comment: @Math Seja como for, o problema do OP está ultrapassado, eu vou manter a minha resposta por me parecer correta dentro do meu entendimento do problema. Recomendo que faças o mesmo! No futuro, com a revisão dos nossos pares _(Peer review)_ a coisa acaba por ficar afinada :)

Comment: É `<` sem igual @Math porque se `length==4` não pode entrar no ciclo. O autor queria uma quantidade variável de dígitos: "...independente do valor da variável quantidade.". E a resposta considerada como certa era a que, na altura, melhor respondia a pergunta a meu ver.