# Como imprimir um valor double com zero a esquerda em java?

Tags: java

Gostaria de imprimir um valor de um Array do tipo double em Java, exemplo:

- `8,00`  <- gostaria que a saída fosse `08,00`.

Como posso fazer isso?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double[] exemplo = {24.00, 8.00, 16.00, 14.00, 10.00};
        
        for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++){

            System.out.printf("%.2f \t| \n", exemplo[l]);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Preencher string com zeros a esquerda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38652/preencher-string-com-zeros-a-esquerda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando a classe [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance()).

`NumberFormat` é a classe base abstrata para todos os formatos de número.
Esta classe fornece uma maneira padrão para formatar e fazer o parse de números.

Esta classe também fornece métodos para determinar quais localidades têm certos padrões de formatação de números e quais os nomes dessas localidades.

Desta forma como deseja formatar um número decimal, devemos utilizar a classe concreta [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) que é uma subclasse de `NumberFormat`.

Ao analisar a documentação da classe `DecimalFormat` vemos que existe um padrão de caracteres especiais que devemos "montar" para gerar a formatação do número de maneira desejada. Estes caracteres especiais devem ser passados no construtor da classe `DecimalFormat`.

| Símbolo | Tipo | Significado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | número | Dígito |
| # | número | Dígito, omite o zero |
| . | número | Separador decimal |

*Estou representando apenas os valores que usei na resposta, para mais opções veja o javadoc da classe `DecimalFormat`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
 double[] exemplo = {24.00, 8.00, 16.00, 14.00, 10.00};
 NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
 for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++){
     System.out.println(nf.format(exemplo[l]));
 }
```

Assim deve ter o resultado esperado.

Caso queira também é possível "formatar" o separador decimal (trocar ponto por vírgula, por exemplo), para isto será necessário utilizar a classe [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html)

Esta classe representa o conjunto de símbolos (como o separador decimal, o separador de agrupamento e assim por diante) necessários na classe `DecimalFormat` para formatar números.

Um caso de uso interessante seria para personalizar uma formatação.

Segue um exemplo:

```
 DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
 dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');

 double[] exemplo = {24.00, 8.00, 16.00, 14.00, 10.00};
 NumberFormat  nf = new DecimalFormat("00.00", dfs);
 for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++){
     System.out.println(nf.format(exemplo[l]));
 }
```

No exemplo acima seria mais simples usar um locale que já possui a vírgula como separador decimal.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
```

Desta forma você não fica dependendo do locale default (que pode inclusive ser mudado por qualquer aplicação rodando na mesma JVM (visto que este é um recurso compartilhado), ou seja, é algo que vc não controla). Até porque, se o locale default for algum outro, ele pode ter outras configurações diferentes, como o separador de milhares (tudo bem que nesse caso não está sendo usado, mas é melhor já usar o locale correto do que usar o default e sair mudando tudo)

Uma lista de *locales* que a linguagem Java possui suporte pode ser vista [aqui](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html#cldrlocale21).

Também é possível fazer uma formatação de valores monetários utilizando a moeda, segue um exemplo:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
nf.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
System.out.println(nf.format(24.00));
//R$ 24,00
```

Desta forme ele já vai formatar como moeda ( que já inclui o "R$"). Mudando os locales vai mudar também a apresentação.

Comment: O mais simples é usar um *locale* que já possui a vírgula como separador decimal: `new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("pt", "BR"))` - assim você não fica dependendo do *locale default* (que pode inclusive ser mudado por qualquer aplicação rodando na mesma JVM, ou seja, é algo que vc não controla). Até porque, se o *locale default* for algum outro, ele pode ter outras configurações diferentes, como o separador de milhares (tudo bem que nesse caso não está sendo usado, mas é melhor já usar o *locale* correto do que usar o *default* e sair mudando tudo)

Comment: Outra opção é criar o formatador com o locale correto (fica "feio" mas enfim): `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR")); ((DecimalFormat) nf).applyPattern("00.00");` - sem isso, cai no mesmo problema: ele vai usar o separador decimal do *locale default*, que nem sempre pode ser o correto (faça `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);` no início do programa e veja que agora ele usa o ponto e não a vírgula). Por fim, se for para mostrar o "R$", pode usar `nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR")); nf.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);` que já inclui o "R$"

Comment: @hkotsubo eu vou adicionar essas ressalvas na resposta, tem problema?

Comment: Sem problemas, pode adicionar :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use o método:

[**`public PrintStream format​(String format, Object... args)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

O método `PrintStream.format()` escreve uma string formatada na saída da stream
utilizando como parâmetros:

- `format`- Uma string de formato, conforme descrito em [Sintaxe da string de formato](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).
- `args`- Argumentos referenciados pelos especificadores de formato na string de formato.

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     double[] exemplo = {24.00, 8.00, 16.00, 14.00, 10.00};
        
     for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++){
        System.out.format("%05.2f \t| \n", exemplo[l]);
     }
  }
}
```

Saída:

```
24.00   | 
08.00   | 
16.00   | 
14.00   | 
10.00   |
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Format#Main.java)</sup>

No caso o especificador de formato `%05.2f` significa:

- `05` - Ao menos cinco caracteres serão impressos e os caracteres faltantes serão completados com zeros a esquerda.
- `.2` - O valor será restrito a precisão de duas casas decimais.
- `f`  - O resultado será formatado como número decimal.

Comment: Vale lembrar que o separador decimal será o do *locale default* que estiver configurado na JVM, que nem sempre pode ser a vírgula. Se quiser forçar um separador específico, pode passar o *locale* para `format`, assim: `System.out.format(new Locale("pt", "BR"), "%05.2f \t| \n", exemplo[l])`